# Python: ways to store the attributes of an object

Tags: python, database

considering the following simplified example:

```
class Atom:

  def __init__(self, name_ID, position, mass, charge):  
    self.name_ID = name_ID # + date
    self.position, self.mass, self.charge = position, mass, charge

  def calculate_equation_of_motion(self):
    self.position, self.mass, self.charge = np.random.rand(3,3),np.random.rand(3,3),np.random.rand(3,3)

  def store_data(self):
    pass

At30 = Atom('test', 0,0,0)
At30.calculate_equation_of_motion()
#At30.store_data()

#At30_copy = load_object(name_ID='atom_30')
#print(At30_copy.charge)
```

of a class that contains 10+ attributes which consist of float and array parameters and variables.

What would you suggest to manage all the calculated arrays in a way I can store an object to be "loaded" later? It might not be clear in this context but in reality, the script takes a while to integrate each array, so I'd like to save the information using a simple approach.

Comment: Other languages call this "serialization", "marshalling", etc. - essentially, representing an object in a way that lets you save it to a file or database and then load it back later. Python calls it "pickling", and [there's a `pickle` module for it that you may find helpful](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). Or [`shelve`, which is similar and might be better for your use case](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html)

Comment: Are you looking to make some class members read only?

Comment: @JonSG not exactly. If I understood the question, I'm not concerned on the readability of the objects I'm creating or the privileges to modify their attributes.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy so using shelve I could later run the script with "updated" attributes from a previous run?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy as it was a ctype object, I wrote the relevant data by  numpy.save()/load()